# Standard for verifying certificates that signed code

Tags: code-signing

When one verifies a certificate that came alongside a signature for some sort of code, is there a standard that specifies what shall be verified?

For example, if I'm to verify a certificate that came alongside a SSL response from a server, I can follow RFC-6125. For emails, there is RFC-5750.

So I was wondering if there is a standard defined practice for code certificates. I understand that typically it won't be much except validating the date, certification path and key usage, but I'd rather refer to a standard.